# The meaning of ? in a java line

Tags: java, string, symbols

as i'm browsing through some java exercises in Programmr, i found this line:

```
   String result = ((num & mask) == 0) ? "even" : "odd";
```

It's a line from a program that determines if a number is odd or even. 
I want to know what does this line exactly means especially the "?" that looks like a rogex meta-character but is not inside the "".

Comment: It's the conditional `? :` operator.

Comment: The `?` and `:` together are the [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). (Although I note that the answer in the duplicate points out that the spec calls this the ["conditional operator"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)).